# How to detect the voltage of a brushless motor

Tags: battery

I took apart the battery and brushless motor from my e-skateboard and want to use it in my own project.

[image: batter + ESC]

[image: motor]

[image: remote]

And here is [the product manual](https://www.jaycar.com.au/medias/sys_master/images/images/9582177091614/GG2402-manualMain.pdf) if it helps.

I really want to re-use the existing hardware, i.e. battery, ESC, motor and or maybe the remote so that I reduce the cost of this project.

But once I took apart the battery and found there is no interface/socket for me to connect the ESC PCB connected to the battery to my RPi(if anyone could figure out how to connect this ESC to RPI, I'd love to hear about that), then I have 2 solutions to get the battery and motor work with my RPi.

1. buy an ESC and use it to connect to battery and RPi and control the motor
2. hack the remote to re-use everything

The most preferable approach is to re-use the existing ESC but I think it's too hard as I mentioned before there is no interface/socket to do that.

Then my 2nd preference is the option 1 as option 2 is hacky(because I need to use 2 of these set of hardware for the 2 rear wheels and not sure whether the 2 remotes will interfere each other, also the remote requires charging).

So if I go with option 1, I will need to know what's the voltage, operation current and peak current of the motor.

From the picture I show above, I can see the battery voltage and its current which are 24V, 2.2Ah. Also from the manual I can see that the watt for motor is 150W. From these information, will I be able to confirm that the Motor also uses 24V and 2.2 A current?

I want to proof my thought by measuring the motor.

But the problem is the motor has 3 cables, so how am I going to measure its voltage and peak current?
(Btw, I have multi-meter)

---

Update:

I use multi-meter and checked the battery's voltage: 28.27V.
Also searched the battery against its model GB T 18287-2000 and found this:

[image]

Here is [the link](https://www.powerstream.com/p/IMP50110140S-60Ah.pdf) to this PDF, table is on the page 2.

As it mentions, the Charging/discharging (fast) is 30A *3.5h,
the Pulse discharging current (max)  is 180A.

Not sure whether is this the max discharge current or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few misconceptions for your device. The battery voltage is 24. The capacity is 2.2 ampere-hours, not 2.2 amperes. This (Ah) is the equivalent of the size of your gas tank, while a current measurement (A) would be more representative of the size of the pipe from the gas tank to the engine. Bigger pipe, more flow, but that's not important.

You have three wires to/from the motor. These devices are typically considered brushless DC motors, also called three phase motors.

The motor controller takes user input and converts it to pulses to the motor, in the correct frequency and the correct order to create the desired speed and direction.

You can expect that the motor has a voltage range rather than a specific voltage, but applying a voltage that is too low will provide insufficient power to move. Applying a voltage that is too high will certainly move the wheel/motor, but going too high means heat. Too much heat is bad.

With a 24v battery, using that figure as a baseline is a good start. One of my brushless motors is rated to 36v, but the manufacturer explained that the motor had sufficient components to handle 48v but I'd have to get an appropriate controller.

You can easily locate a 24v brushless controller, aka ESC, electronic speed controller and a servo tester to experiment with the motor. Your current figure should be checked at the battery, as the three leads for the motor are going to have pulsed current and will not be easily read with a digital or analog meter. One could determine useful information with an oscilloscope, but that's not part of the question.

With respect to the current draw, you've noted that the motor is 150 Watts. 150 divided by 24 is approximately 6 (amperes) at maximum power. Your ESC should be rated higher than that and a ten ampere ESC gives you some leeway.

The battery does not have a label indicating C rating (maximum discharge current) but it's safe to consider that 6 amperes (maximum) current draw (slightly less than 3C) is within normal limits.

One should aim to limit discharge of a lithium chemistry battery to no more than eighty percent depth, providing for (2.2 x 0.8) 1.76 ampere hours capacity. Pulling 6 amps at maximum current provides for somewhat less than 20 minutes operating time. This also matches with the battery marking of 52 WHr on the label. 150 Watts motor power divided by the approximately 50 WHr figure gives you one-third of an hour (20 minutes). It's unlikely you'd be operating at full current and for the purposes of this answer, 3 amperes current gives you about 40 minutes operating time between charges.

Consider also to install a current measuring/counting device such as a watts-up meter to the battery of your new construction. This provides you with instantaneous current reading but more useful, it provides total ampere-hour consumption. You can zero the device after the charge is complete, and check it regularly during use of the device, ceasing to enjoy your ride prior to reaching the 1.76 ampere-hour threshold.

Comment: hi @fre_dot_u, thank you so much for your detailed explanation. After reading your answer, should I get an ESC with 10A and 24V capacity? Are there any other requirements for this ESC? Also I have found the information for battery and updated in my question. Could you please have a look?

Comment: I don't think the included table is an accurate one for this battery. The part number includes "5C" which might be the discharge rate (5 * 2.2 Ah = 11A) which is quite a bit lower than the 20,000mA (20A) in the table. You won't pay much more for a 20A ESC, so get that value instead. Note also that the servo tester should also include ESC capability, as not all of them do.

Comment: great to know one more trick about how to read battery info :) I finally placed my order of the ESC after a whole week searching for suitable one~!!!

Comment: Btw, to conclude, the answer to my question is, instead of measuring the motor, measure the battery to get an estimated motor voltage. Am I correct?

Comment: I've not seen a BLDC motor that has a higher voltage applied than the source. It doesn't mean they don't exist, but it's not a practical implementation, in my opinion. The controller pulses the power to the coils in the motor, effectively creating a PWM signal to mimic voltage levels necessary to achieve the desired speed. Having higher voltage than the source would then require a more robust controller circuit than that of the non-boosted voltage. Yes, measure the battery but expect to see lower figures on an o-scope.